Error when creating a new item prototype (zabbix proxmox)
I'm using Zabbix 7.0.4 and I'm using the template Proxmox VE by HTTP that has predefined item prototypes like these:

I want to create a new item prototype for Proxmox VE by HTTP that calculates the % of used memory

Yet, I receive this error.

I plan to do the same thing for filesystems to use them in Grafana and receive alerts.
I have tried with 100*last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.node.memused[{#NODE.NAME}])/last(/Proxmox VE by HTTP/proxmox.node.memtotal[{#NODE.NAME}])  but I receive same error

As a rule of thumb, the easiest way to get started would be to clone an existing trigger prototype and modify it to suit your needs.
In this case specific case, I have tried to create the trigger using your definition with the same template (Proxmox VE by HTTP) and it worked perfectly. But I have done this under the "Node discovery" discovery rule because this is where the proxmox.node.memtotal[{#NODE.NAME}] is getting defined. So I suspect that you have tried to create this trigger under a different discovery rule.

I am using node discovery, but I'm not trying to create a trigger, I'm trying to create an item prototype so that it could be imported on Grafana to create the alert when the memo is above a certain percentage because I couldn't find a way to do that directly on Grafana. Also the trigger you have created is already there in the template. I'm not sure if I understood what you did exactly, if you can elaborate on it more please.
